# Transforming an array into an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to do an opposite of flattening an array.

I have the following input JSON array of **4** elements:

```
[
  {
    "nestedObj": {
      "id":12
    }
  },
  {
    "nestedObj": {
      "id":555
    }
  },
  {
    "nestedObj": {
      "id":555
    }
  },
  {
    "nestedObj" :{
      "id":771
    }
  }
]
```

I want to transform it to an *array of arrays*, where each subarray has elements of the same `nestedObj.id` grouped up together.

I can assume the initial JSON is sorted by `nestedObj.id`.

In the above example, the `id` of `nestedObj` of 2nd and 3rd element are the same (`555`), so those elements would be grouped into one sub-array.

This would be the result, an array of **only 3** sub-array elements:

```
[
  [{
    "nestedObj": {
      "id":12
    }
  }],
  [{
    "nestedObj": {
      "id":555
    }
  },
  {
    "nestedObj": {
      "id":555
    }
  }],
  [{
    "nestedObj" :{
      "id":771
    }
  }]
]
```

And this is the code that gets me what I want:

```
const data = [ /* ...the above input data... */ ];
let result = [];
let prevId = null;
for (let elem of data) {
  let currId = elem.nestedObj.id;
  if (currId === prevId) {
    result[result.length - 1].push({...elem});
  } else {
    result.push([{...elem}]);
  }
  prevId = currId;
}
```

But as you can see... the code is very declarative. It's not very JavaScript-like, in a functional programming sense.

How can I re-write it using e.g. reduce or other 'modern JS' techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just group the objects.

```js
let array = [{ nestedObj: { id: 12 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 555 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 555 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 771 } }],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
        (r[o.nestedObj.id] = r[o.nestedObj.id] || []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd elements (of the same id) are not grouped up together, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by id using the function `reduce`, extract the grouped values using the function `Object.values`, and finally `map` the array to build the desired output.

*This is assuming we have only one attribute called `nestedObj`*

```js
let arr = [{ nestedObj: { id: 12 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 555 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 555 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 771 } }],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {nestedObj: {id}}) => {
      (a[id] || (a[id] = [])).push(id);
      return a;
    }, {})).map(r => r.map(id => ({nestedObj: {id}})));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map to group the items with same id then get the final values from the Map

```js
const data = [{ nestedObj: { id: 12 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 555 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 555 } }, { nestedObj: { id: 771 } }]

const map = new Map;

data.forEach(o => {
  const {nestedObj:{id}} = o;
  map.has(id) ? map.get(id).push(o) : map.set(id,[o]);
});

console.log([...map.values()])
```